# Convert template literal to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React component in which it receives a prop `codeBlock`, it is then stored in the state of the component.

which has following structure:

```js
codeBlock = {
  code: `<div></div>`,
  language: 'html'
}
```

I want to convert this `codeBlock.code` which is a template literal string into a html element, so that when I add/append this while rendering the element I will get the DOM element not the literal string.

Things I've tried so far,

In the `componentDidMount()`, I tried two different ways:-

1. Using DOMParser:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const output = parser.parseFromString(this.state.codeBlock.code, 'text/html');
  this.setState({
    output
  });
}
```

This method doesn't work and throws this error:
objects are not valid as a react child (found: [object htmldocument])

2. Using String.raw:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    output: String.raw `${this.state.codeBlock.code}`
  });
}
```

This method prints the template string as it is and doesn't create any element.

Screenshot:
[image]

In the below section of the code it should render as html element instead of string.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @laruiss I have updated the question. Sorry I earlier provided less info on the problem.

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by "html string". Your first attempt creates a DOM element, not a string at all. And the value generated by the template literal expression already *is* a string, you can use it like any other string (and `String.raw` doesn't make sense the way you use it). [What do you actually need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi By html string I meant actual element, so when added in the DOM it gets rendered as an element not as a string. Suppose this is what I want to render `<div class="container"></div>`, it should create an element with class container without literally rendering the given string as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be not to pass a string but a React element (or both):

```
codeBlock = {
  code: "<div></div>", // string here
  rendered: <div></div>, // jsx here
  language: 'html'
}
```

This you can easily render into a React component. However, if you *really* have to deal with a string of html (as the name `codeBlock`, and the availability of other languages would suggest), you would have to use `innerHTML` or React's equivalent [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Notice that it doesn't matter (or help) that the string value was originally created using template literal syntax. It makes no difference to the component that is receiving the string.

Comment: At one point of time I thought of this, but wanted to keep my code as minimal as possible, that's why I came across this problem. Will check the other way as well too. Thanks.

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti It's still unclear whether that `codeBlock` is hardcoded somewhere (maybe as one of a few choices) or actually completely dynamically generated data. Btw, if you don't care about whitespace it should be possible to reconstruct a string from a jsx element value.

Comment: you are right, the code is hardcoded, And actually I do care about the white spaces here, as I want to print the code as well as the output of the code, I have attached the screenshot in the question

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` this method gives me desired output. thanks for the help. But I'm not sure if I should be using this in my code. But the code will always be hardcoded though, so I don't think it should be the problem here! What do you think of this?

Comment: Yes, it's not a problem if the html is hardcoded and whoever changes that code remembers how it is used. Using jsx alongside of it would emphasise the usage, but of course lead to duplication. It's a trade-off.

Comment: I'll be the only one who is going to maintain this code, so it will be fine also since its hardcoded, so its cool!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `innerHTML`.

HTML:

```
<div id="elem"></div>
```

JS:

```
const codeBlock = {
  code: `<div class="container"></div>`,
  language: 'html'
}

const elem = document.getElementById("elem");
elem.innerHTML = codeBlock.code;
```

Comment: Sorry but this won't work, cause it's in the react component, earlier I did not put up the whole scenario, sorry for that. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` also goes against React's design patterns. The best way to handle this would be conditionally rendering this from within the `render()` function.

Comment: @Brett84c, its not his fault, earlier I did not included the whole scenario in the question. Though I did not get the conditional rendering point. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create html based on specific data that is called from a server? Can't you just add this html directly inside the `render()` function exactly where it needs to be placed?

Comment: Yes its getting rendered dynamically, depending on the props. So whatever string I send via the code key of `codeBlock` object which is received as a prop, needs to be interpreted as HTML string while rendering.

Comment: @Brett84c If this would use React design patterns, it wouldn't pass a "html string" as props in the first place but a proper react element.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, that's why I was trying to clarify what they are trying to do before giving more information. At this point, it sounds like they want to get their html from a server and set it in their DOM which still doesn't jive with React's design pattern but is still allowed via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which is aptly named.

Comment: @Brett84c Yup, exactly my answer :-)